# File upload not working in expressionengine 2.10.0

Tags: file-uploads, ee2-upgrades, file-manager, ee, uploads

i just got expression engine 2.10.0 and i made a channel with a file upload field, when i try to upload file i click on `Add File> Upload File> Brows`, after selecting my file when i click on `upload file` it does nothing and just waiting. i checked in browser developer area in `net> Html` tab i have this message:

```
Reload the page to get source for: mysite.com/system/index.php?/cp/content_files_modal/upload_file&S=1301649de23f656ed526f3d407847484
```

all permissions are right and upload destination is ok.
any suggestion what could it be??

Comment: A new version out yesterday with bugs? I always suggest letting others be early adopters, and the authors working out the bugs before posting questions like these.

Comment: what do you mean exactly? you are saying i should not ask this question or should not ask here or what?

Comment: I simply mean that it's quite possibly it's a core file bug and EE 2.10 isn't out in the wild yet; I won't even have time to download it and deploy a test VM to help you out this week. Hopefully someone else can help you! ..but if you deploy a new version right away, please take some time to debug yourself before asking here, because you asked for trouble adopting so early.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue recently when PHP was reconfigured. It turned out PHP's fileinfo extension wasn't enabled. Fixing that fixed the upload problem I was having. Might at least be something to check on in your case too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm one of the developers at EllisLab and I just tried uploading a file on a 2.10.0 install of mine and had no issues. Have you tried disabling extensions?

Comment: yes i disabled all extensions and still have that problem

Comment: Are you using the native File Manager or the native File field or something else?

Comment: Also, when you upgraded did you update all of the files in system/expressionengine/config/ besides your config.php and database.php files?

Comment: yes i'm using native file manager, first i upgrade an old version, it didn't work, then i installed a new clear project for test but it didn't work too